# Global Variables in ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET Core and currently have a large set of keys, such as stripe account keys. Instead of having them spread throughout the project in different classes I would like to place them all together in json where they could be accessed globally. I have tried placing them in appsettings.json but cannot access them anywhere.

Comment: Putting them in appsettings is a great place for this kind of thing (remember to add that file to your gitignore!)  To access them in the controllers you need to use DI.

Comment: Try putting in appsettings.json and then create a class which will help in storing those values

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I often do this kind of thing with connection strings and other global constants.  First create a class for those variables that you need.  In my project it is `MDUOptions` but whatever you want.

```
public class MDUOptions
{
    public string mduConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string secondaryConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your Startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
Action<MDU.MDUOptions> mduOptions = (opt =>
{
    opt.mduConnectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:mduConnection"];
});
services.Configure(mduOptions);
services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MDUOptions>>().Value);
```

Now you use DI to access it in code:

```
public class PropertySalesRepository : IPropertySalesRepository
{
    private static string _mduDb;

    public PropertySalesRepository(MDUOptions options)
    {
        _mduDb = options.mduConnectionString;
    }
    ....
}
```

In my case the only property I wanted was the string but I could have used the entire options class.

Comment: Thanks @nurdyguy, this answer is very clear! Just one follow up, how do I get the MDUOptions parameter you use in the PropertySalesRepository constructor?

Comment: The dependency injection built in to the framework will populate the `options` variable.  The line `services.AddSingleton(...)` is critical for this.

Comment: Here is ore info about Dependency Injection, it is MAGIC!  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @nurdyguy why not creating a static class instead?

Comment: @OffirPe'er Do you mean a static class with a bunch of hardcoded string values?  What happens when you have different values for different environments (dev vs qa vs prod)?  Using the `IOptions` is the best way to do this kind of thing, though the implementation has changed a bit in the last 2 years:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Ok, this is the way:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 19):

In appsettings.json keep the variables.

```
{
    "foo": "value1",
    "bar": "value2",
}
```

Create **AppSettings** class.

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string foo { get; set; }

    public string bar { get; set; }
}
```

In **Startup.cs** file register.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration);
}
```

Usage,

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettings;

    public MyController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings;
    }
    var fooValue = _appSettings.Value.foo;
    var barValue = _appSettings.Value.bar;
}
```

Comment: How are you declaring variables inside of a class?