# How to set global data in startup.cs upon logging in .net core 3.1 web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, global-variables, asp.net-core-3.1, vs-web-application-project

My .net core 3.1 web application starts with the user having to SignIn, along with selecting the Company/Branch (CompanyCode). 
Now how and where do i save this application data 'CompanyCode', for use in rest of the session.
I have figured out a way to set other static Global variables (constants) in the startup.cs file.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            Action<GlobalData> gData = (g =>
            {
                g.CompanyCode = 2;
                g.DummyCust = 3;
                g.Type_Personal = 0;
                g.Type_Asset = 1;
                g.Type_Bank = 2;

                g.Type_Customer = 1;
                g.Type_Staff = 2;

            });
            services.Configure(gData);
            services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<GlobalData>>().Value);

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<ImgContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ImgContext")));
        }
```

GlobalData Class Definition:

```
namespace Imagetech.Data
{
    public class GlobalData
    {
        public int CompanyCode { get; set; }
        public int Type_Personal { get; set; }
        public int Type_Asset { get; set; }
        public int Type_Bank { get; set; }
        public int Type_Customer { get; set; }
        public int Type_Staff { get; set; }
        public int DummyCust { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now CompanyCode being a dynamic Global data to be set after login; how can i achieve it ?
Pls do help.
Thanks

Comment: As this is a web site, I assume there will be multiple simultaneous users, therefore any kind of global 'user' setting will be wrong.   When you login, the server will send back a token that identifies that user, and then the browser will send that token back to the server to allow it to identify the user settings.  I would suggest you look at some of the examples on https://asp.net

Comment: agreed with @Neil , you need t use tokens for login. Take a look at using JWT.

Answer (score 0):

The best, and easiest way to do this is

1. Upon successful login, return the companyCode to caller
2. Caller (may be a javascript app, will store the companyCode globally e.g. localstorage.)
3. Have the caller include the companyCode in request headers.
4. That way you can just read the headers and get the company code.

A few ways to make this easier -

- use JWT for authentication, that way you can simply include the companyCode in your token, and nobody can tamper with it.
- Store the companyCode in httpOnly cookie upon login. Cookies are then automatically included in every request to your webapp. Of course for this solution to work you'll need to ask your users to have cookies enabled (which is okay, many websites do.)

Answer (score 0):

> Now how and where do i save this application data 'CompanyCode', for use in rest of the session.

You could also use DI in your login controller/razor pages to  get and set the `CompanyCode`, for example

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<GlobalData> _globalData;

    public AccountController(IOptions<GlobalData> globalData)
    {
        _globalData = globalData;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
       var originalData = _globalData.Value.CompanyCode;
       //after login successfully
       //replace below 100 with your selected `CompanyCode`,
       _globalData.Value.CompanyCode = 100

        return View();
    }
}
```

Refer to [Global Variables in ASP.Net Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654307/global-variables-in-asp-net-core-2/52654416)

Comment: How would this work if 2 users from different companies logged in?

Answer (score -1):

One quick way is to centralize all you constants (assuming those values are fixed during the development, and not configuration settings), in a static class