# How to add global values in .NET Core 3?

Tags: api, .net-core

I need to set global values and read it from anywhere in my project.
what is the scenario, if AddSingleton how?

I have seen this, but it's not working for me:
[Global Variables in ASP.Net Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654307/global-variables-in-asp-net-core-2/52654416)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Noah is very good, however for simpler cases you generally want to:

1. Create a static class that holds all your data, in the root namespace

   ```
   public static class Cache
   {
       public static string Value1 => "Example";
       public static int Value2 => 42;
   }
   ```
2. Done

You can access it's values system-wide, like so:

```
var mySharedStringValue = Cache.Value1;
```

If you need to "load" those values in the startup, you can change the signature of the properties to

```
public static string Value1 { get; private set; }
```

and use a [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) or a simple static initialization method that you call in the Startup.cs class when the APP is starting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a static value globally, I'd suggest using the [configuration system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for that. It allows injecting the configuration wherever needed for reading.

If you need to share data that can change, you need some shared thread-safe mechanism. One option built into the framework is to use the [in-memory cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-imemorycache), which is a global shared cache injectable anywhere.